# HTML, CSS : Why does my layout mess up on different resolutions?

Tags: css, html, screen-resolution

I am trying to make a portfolio kind of thing with HTML and CSS and my layout looks really good on my resolution of 1920 * 1080 but when i change the resolution everything moves around and everything looks really bad.

Can anybody point out to me where I am going wrong with my code and provide me with a solution to my problem?

--- Edited new code

How it looks on 1920 * 1080:
http://screencast.com/t/mq8H3baBxIi

So i have changed the advised things but i'm still getting that, for example, when i change from my screen resolution of 1920 * 1080 to 1280 * 1024 to test how it looks the comment areas pull on top of the grey 'contact me' box so that it ends up like me picture on this link:
http://screencast.com/t/xZEwSgwdqP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolioStyles.css" />
    </head>
        <body>
             <div id="pageTitleContact"> CONTACT ME</div>
             <div id="sideBar">             </div>
             <div id="commentSideBar"> </div>
    <div id="logos">
    <ul>
      <div id="home"><li><a href="portfolioHome.html"><img src="home.png" alt="list item 1" /></a></li></div>
      <div id="aboutMe"><li><a href="portfolioAboutMe.html"><img src="aboutMe.png" alt="list item 2" /></a></li></div>
      <div id="achievements"><li><a href="portfolioAchievement.html"><img src="achievement.png" alt="list item 3" /></a></li></div>
      <div id="hobbies"><li><a href="portfolioHobbies.html"><img src="Hobbies.png" alt="list item 4" /></a></li></div>
      <div id="contactMe"><li><a href="portfolioContactMe.html"><img src="contactMeHighlighted.png" alt="list item 4" /></a></li></div>
    </ul>
    </div>
            <textarea id="contactMeTextarea">





            </textarea>

    <div id="Commentsection">
            <form action="postcommentandreturn.php" method="post">

            <div id="nameAreaTitle">
            Name:</div><input type="text" id="nameArea" name="name" />
            <br>

            <textarea placeholder="Insert Comment Here..." type="text" id="commentArea"  name="comment"></textarea>
            <div id="submitLocation"><input type="submit" id="submitComment"  value="Submit"/></div>

            </form>
    </div>
<!--comment section-->

<div id="postedComments">



  <tr>

  <td><div id="postersName"> </div>
  </td>
   </tr>

  <tr>

  <td><div id="commentDate"></div></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

  <td>
  <textarea id="postersComment"></textarea></td>

  </tr>

</table>
</div>


        </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#sideBar {
    background-color: #111111;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;

}

#commentSideBar {
    background-color: #111111;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    right:0;

}
#logos {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-20px;
}

#home {
    margin-top:50px;
}

#homeInfo {
    resize: none;    
    position:fixed;
    display: block;
    height:400px;
    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#3f3f3f;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-align:left;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:40px;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin-left:-350px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}


#pageTitleContact {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top:-400px;
    margin-left:-400px;
    color:limegreen;
    font-size:100px;
    font-family:Arial;
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#aboutMe {
    margin-top:100px;

}

#achievements {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:-7px;
}

#hobbies {
    margin-top:100px;
}

#contactMe {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}


#contactMeTextarea {
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    resize: none;    
    position:fixed;
    display: block;
    height:600px;
    width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#3f3f3f;
    color:whitesmoke;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:40px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#Commentsection {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:140px;
    margin-top:-300px;

}

#nameAreaTitle {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nameArea {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:30px;
}

#commentArea {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    resize: none; 
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:20px;  
}

#submitComment {
    width:100px;
    font-size:20px;

}

#postedComments{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:10px; 
    margin-right:10px;
    width:280px;
    background-color:grey;

}
#postersName {

    width:260px;
    height:25px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#commentDate {
    width:260px;
    height:25px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#postersComment {
    width:275px;
    height:200px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding-left:10px;
    resize:none;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: Start by NOT nesting all your page elements inside `<head></head>`.

Comment: I don't think you will get a satisfying answer with a question like this. You are basicly just asking to fix your site. At least try to put it online, so people can have a look at the result and point you in the right direction.

Comment: I wasn't really planning on putting it online :/ am just practicing

Comment: You have a few issues with your HTML being invalid, the `<body>` belongs after the `<head>` not inside it.  And you have `<li>` elements on their own inside `<div>`s, they need to be in a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.  You are missing the opening `<table>` as well.

Comment: Have you met http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at it too closely, you can probably add a container div or something that wraps all your code up, and then assign a `min-width` attribute to ensure that it never goes smaller than the given size.
Your layout seems to be relying on the width of your `body` and as your window size changes so will the width of your body.  Having a wrapper with a `min-width` or declared `width` will make it so a horizontal scroll bar will appear when users have a window smaller than the width of your container.

And like others have stated, you have some nesting issues.  General page layout will look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Head Content -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <ul>
      <li><!-- List Item --></li>
      <li><!-- List Item --></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have done some of the solutions you and the others have suggested and added some pictures of how it looks on my normal resolution and the another resolution as an example

Comment: Right after the opening `<body>` tag add this: `<div id="container" style="position: relative; min-width: 1900px;">` and then right before the closing `</body>` tag add a `</div>`.  The problem appears to be just as I've described, but with absolutely positioned elements like you're using the parent will need a position declaration, like the `position: relative` that I added.